# disable the user for 2 hrs if the wrong password is entered 3 times with php cookies

Tags: php, mysql, session-cookies

this is my code i want to add if conditions for disable user when entered wrong password. please help me  out.

```
<?php

if(isset($_COOKIE["enabled"]))
{
    if($_POST["username"]=="Master" and $_POST["password"]=="123")
    {
        if(isset($_POST["rem"]))
            setcookie("valid","yes",time()+2592000);
        else
            setcookie("valid","yes");

        header("location: welcome.php");
    }
    else
        header("location:login.php?msg=1");
}
else
    header("location: login.php?msg=5");

?>
```

Comment: What specific troubles are you having?

Comment: This is not something you should do with cookies. A user can just delete the cookie and try again. You need to keep track of this on the server side, most likely in your database.

Comment: i just want to add condition to this for disabling user on wrong password for three time for 2 hrs.. i know user can delete cookies.. but just to learn and practice i want your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your are looking to manage database users failed logins, in mysql there is no automatic lock mechanism but it can be done using auditing log on failure event and using triggers for failure event.
 **Solution for this is described on this [post !](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/668/audit-logins-on-mysql-database/1434#1434)**